# Error in curl when authenticating into JIRA

Tags: curl, jira, curly-braces, jira-plugin

```
curl  -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" -d '{"username":"admin","password":"admin"}' http://localhost:2990/jira/rest/auth/1/session
```

I used the above query in DOS and I always get the following error :

> {"errorMessages":["Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): expected a
>   valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or
>   'null')\n at [Source:
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@1fd9611; line: 1,
>   column: 2]"]}

I tried many permutations and combinations .. Still it did not work ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me on OSX. 39 is a single quote char but I don't see where that comes from.

Answer (score 4):

Its a windows thing, 
try to replace `'` with `"` and `"` with `"""`.

```
curl  -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" -d "{"""username""":"""admin""","""password""":"""admin"""}" ...
```